# Finding how many terms required to estimate function with in some error

Tags: calculus

How many terms of the Taylor series for $ln(1+x)$ centered at $x = 0$ do you need to estimate the value
of $ln(1.4)$ to three decimal places (that is, to within .0005)?

$$f(x)=ln(1+x)$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$$
$$f''(x)=-(1+x)^{-2}$$
$$f'''(x)=2(1+x)^{-3}$$
$$f^4(x)=-6(1+x)^{-4}$$
$$f^n(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n-1} n!}{(1+x)^n}$$
$$f^{n+1}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n} (n+1)!}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$$

$$|R_n(x)| <= \frac{M|x-a|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} <= 0.0005$$
a=0,
$$|R_n(x)| <= \frac{M|x|^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} <= 0.0005$$

$$M =\frac{ (n+1)!}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$$

I know how to solve the inequality but to get the M, What number do I plugin for $x$ to find the maximum error bound? Is it $0.4$?

Answer (score 2):

By Taylor expansion around $x=0$ $$\log(1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}n$$ This is an alternating series and you need to add $p$ terms to bound the error $$M_p=\frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}\leq \epsilon$$ The solution of equation$$\frac{x^{p+1}}{p+1}= \epsilon$$ is given in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $$p=-1-\frac{W\left(-\frac{\log (x)}{\epsilon }\right)}{\log (x)}$$ Since the argument, you can use the expansion given in the Wikipedia page $$W(z)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(z)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

Using $x=0.4$ and $\epsilon=0.0005$, this would give $${W\left(-\frac{\log (x)}{\epsilon }\right)}\approx 5.76549$$ and then $p=5.29$. So, six terms would be required.

Just for check with the partial sums $$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}n$$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & S_p & |S_{p+1}-S_p| \\
 1 & 0.400000 & 0.080000 \\
 2 & 0.320000 & 0.021333 \\
 3 & 0.341333 & 0.006400 \\
 4 & 0.334933 & 0.002048 \\
 5 & 0.336981 & 0.000683 \\
 6 & 0.336299 & \color{red}{0.000234} \\
 7 & 0.336533 & 0.000082 \\
 8 & 0.336451 & 0.000029
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the alternating series estimation error..using x = 0.4, the error simply becomes $\frac{(0.4)^{n+1}}{(n+1)} <= 0.0005 $ and by plugging in some values for n, I found n has to be 6 at least which was  the correct solution.

Comment: Sorry for the intrusion, but is [this account](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/82323/claude-leibovici) yours? If so, why don't you delete it?

Comment: @AlexM.. First time I see it ! How do I delete it without deleting the current one ? Thanks for helping.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Flag [the only post associated to that account](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/419541) to the attention of a moderator, asking for that account to be deleted. Alternatively, use [the standard contact form](https://math.stackexchange.com/contact) to contact the SE team and choose the appropriate reason ("I need to delete my user profile" or "Other"), but take care to explain clearly which of your two accounts you want deleted - you don't want to lose the high reputation one!